# Why moderators of previous years remain moderators?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

From [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), I can see that a lot of the moderators of previous years still currently have the moderator privilege, **I'm not saying this is a bad thing**, but it's kind of counter-intuitive to me since it doesn't look like how moderators work in other environments.

So here are my questions:

1. Is it true that moderators are able to keep their privileges until they willingly resign, even after the year they were elected?
2. If so, what's the reason behind this? The more the better(of course quality matters, this goes without saying)?

Comment: An election is perminant in the first instance, although I'm sure if a mod went rouge and started banning people at random they wouldn't last long

Comment: See also: [Should Community Moderators be "elected for life", or have terms?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/984)

Comment: See also: [Are moderators forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117633)

Answer (score 13):

> Is it true that moderators are able to keep their privileges until they willingly resign, even after the year they were elected?

Yes.  Either that or they could potentially have their privileges revoked by SE.

> If so, what's the reason behind this? The more the better(of course quality matters, this goes without saying)?

Because the community has recognized that they are trustworthy enough and capable enough to moderate the site.  Unless they've demonstrated an inability to perform their duties, there's no reason to remove them.

---

Do you have some compelling reason to believe that moderators are generally going to be unable to perform their duties adequately after they have served for a year, thus warranting a need for re-election?

---

> it doesn't look like how moderators work in other environments

Really?  In virtually every other similar environment I've been involved in site moderators aren't elected to begin with.  It's exceedingly rare.  For the vast majority of sites they're simply appointed by the community managers/site admins.

Comment: There have been moderators that have "agreed" to resign, but it is very rare.

Comment: [See the moderators help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) " Moderators are elected for life, though they may resign (or, in very rare cases, be removed)."

Comment: No, I was thinking if we don't change moderators, why do we need annually elections。

Comment: More are added as needed...I believe that's also on the help page.

Comment: @ZinanXing to keep pace with growth.

Comment: @Zinan the site grows ever larger, flags are ever growing

Comment: @ZinanXing It's because two moderators resigned their position, and to accommodate any increased workload. There is no guarantee to be an election every year, and in the past there has been two in a year.